# How can I use collection select with has_one association

Tags: select, collections, has-one

I have 2 models:

```
class Brigade < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  has_one :country
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
end
```

In my _form.html.erb I have:

```
<%= form_for(@brigade) do |f| %>
     <p>
       <%= f.label :title %>
       <%= f.text_field :title %>
     </p>
     <p>
       <%= f.label "Country" %>
       <%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.all, :id, :title %>
     </p>
<% end %>
```

Running this I have a message:

```
undefined method `country_id' for #<Brigade:0x9a89cac> (ActionView::Template::Error)
```

I think in this case Rails must automatically join `country_id` to `brigade`, but it is not.

I don't know where is my mistake. Is it necessary to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`?